# JwtAccessTokenConverter and JwtTokenStore was drepreciated. What can be used instead?

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I'm creating an application with Spring Security. I need to use JWT with JwtAccessTokenConverter and JwtTokenStore was drepreciated. When I import, it shows that it is depreciated. What can be used instead?

```
package com.devsuperior.dscatalog.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); // return a instance
    }
    
    
    // Objects can access a token JWT: ready, write, create, etc
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey("MY-JWT-SECRET");
        return tokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003705/jwtaccesstokenconverterconfigurer-alternate

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the entire [**Spring Security OAuth project**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) is deprecated. I assume that you want an alternative for the Authorization Server. If this case, you could try using [**Spring Authorization Server**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server)

> The Spring Authorization Server project, led by the Spring Security team, is focused on delivering OAuth 2.1 Authorization Server support to the Spring community.

It now supported lots of [features](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/releases/tag/0.2.0) and you can wait for the fully supported OIDC implementation in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

### I adjusted pom.xml to that dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are asking for the same reason, but in the previous version of accessTokenConverter I could override the extractAuthentication methood, so I could map the authorities form the token to a spring role. In spring security 6 resource server, I could use this code

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(customizer -> customizer
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> getJwtAuthenticationToken(jwt)))
        );
        return http.build();
    }

    private AbstractAuthenticationToken getJwtAuthenticationToken(Jwt jwt) {
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, extractAuthorities(jwt));
    }
```